# What is the API to get the List of all INTENTS and ENTITIES of LUIS APP

Tags: java, api, postman, azure-language-understanding

Actually, We are not getting the List of all Intents and Entities from the LUIS APP after changing Version 3.0. Before when it was in version 2.0 we used the below API to get the List of all INTENTS but now it's not working and I am unable to find the API's to the latest version of LUIS APP.

Can anyone help me with the API to get the LIST of all INTENTS and ENTITIES from the LUIS APP

[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhjwA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not properly formed, which is why you are getting a 404 Not Found error. First of all, it's not a good idea to share your subscription key or LUIS app id. I would redact those values in your screenshot.

Here is the [LUIS v3.0-preview API Reference](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c1a). I looked at "Get intent" under models, but it's looking for a specific intent name, so I don't think that's what you want. But it's the API that is called via the "/intents" resource path. There are a number of issues with your actual request.

- I believe this is still in preview, so API version should be `v3.0-preview`, not v3.0
- Missing *authoring* from the path
- Subscription key should not be a query string. This needs to be send in request headers.

Also, make sure you have the correct subscription key and app ID. Since you provided the values I did try to make the API call (with None intent name), but I got 401 unauthorized due to wrong subscription key or API endpoint. You can click on your region from the API reference and the site will allow you to make the appropriate call by entering in the required information. It will generate the correct Request URL for you.

If you check all this out and it's still not working for you, let me know what additional problems you are having and I'll try to help further.